# How do I render a model with a different template based on a model attribute

Tags: python, django, templates, model

this seems like a really basic thing, so I'm expecting this to be a straight forward answer... sorry if this is dumb.

I have a model called Item. It has a headline, body text, links, etc. However, it also has an attribute 'type' which is either 'video' 'podcast' or 'article'.

At the moment, I use a generic class 'DetailView' to render a detail page for Item. The template is called item_detail.html and is passed to the request from DetailView.

All I want to do is have the view send a different template based on the 'type' attribute. So if item.type = 'article' render an article template, if item.type = 'video' render a video template.

Is this possible whilst still using DetailView?

This is what I tried in the view:

```
class ItemDetailView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Item
     if Item.type == 'video':
        template_name = 'curate/item_video.html'
```

This didn't do what I wanted - in fact the template just rendered as normal. Am I missing something? I also considered creating an entirely new model for 'videos' 'podcasts' and 'articles' but I'd rather avoid this and have an 'Item' as a powerful content type on the website.

views.py

```
class ItemDetailView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Item
     if Item.type == 'video':
        template_name = 'curate/item_video.html'
```

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=1000)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2000,
                            choices=type_choices,
                            default='article',
                            blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_template_names method to return conditional tempelates.

```
class ItemDetailView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Item

    def get_template_names(self):
        item = self.get_object()
        if item.type == 'video':
            return ['curate/item_video.html']
        elif item.type == 'podcast':
            return ['curate/item_podcast.html']
        ...........................
        else:
            return ['curate/default.html']
```

Other way to do it, would be to pass Item object in context and have conditions in template.

Comment: Thanks - I knew it would be simple. That is running me an error that model isn't defined. Even if I put 'item' or 'Item' in there.

Comment: you need to use get_object() to use current object. model is really a class of Item. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `self.get_object()` from `DetailView`

so the code will look like this:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    self.object = self.get_object()    
    if self.object.type == 'video':
        return ...
    else:
        return ...
```